# Hibernate AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, hibernate

I know this question has been raised many times before, but I am still confused where the mistake might be in my case:

AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.collab.collabplatform.persistance.entities.CategoryModel.category2projectRel[com.collab.collabplatform.persistance.keys.Category2ProjectRelKey]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category2projectRel`
(
    `project_id`  bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `category_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`, `category_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_category2project_project_id` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `project` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_category2project_category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;
```

and the entities and key classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"category2projectRel\"")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Category2ProjectRelModel {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Category2ProjectRelKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("project_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private ProjectModel project;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("category_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private CategoryModel category;
}
```

&

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class Category2ProjectRelKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "project_id")
    Long projectId;

    @Column(name = "category_id")
    Long categoryId;
}
```

&

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"category\"")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class CategoryModel extends BaseEntity {

    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String color;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    List<Category2ProjectRelKey> category2projectRel;
}
```

&

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"project\"")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProjectModel extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="location_id")
    private LocationModel location;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private OffsetDateTime creationDate;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "termination_date")
    private OffsetDateTime terminationDate;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private Boolean virtual;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    List<Category2ProjectRelKey> category2projectRel;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    List<Project2TagRelKey> project2tagRel;
}
```

Comment: please check my answer and put other entity in your question

Answer (score 0):

**@ManyToOne @OneToMany @OneToOne @ManyToMany** annotations should be used with Entity classes (classes annotated with @Entity)

So, in **CategoryModel** class, you use @OneToMany with class **Category2ProjectRelKey**, which is not an entity.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category") // this annotation should target an entity class
List<Category2ProjectRelKey> category2projectRel;
```

**@Embeddable** annotation on a class, does not mean it's an entity, but means that it represents a set of a column of more that could be included in other entities.